# Swift NSLayoutConstraint centering UIView to centered top of sibling

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint

I'm getting the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Invalid pairing of layout attributes'

Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
static func addViewConstraintsCenterTop(constrainObject : UIView, toSibling : UIView) {

    constrainObject.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    var constraints:[NSLayoutConstraint] = []

    var constW = NSLayoutConstraint(item: constrainObject, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: toSibling, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    constraints.append(constW)

    var constH = NSLayoutConstraint(item: constrainObject, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: toSibling, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    constraints.append(constH)

    constrainObject.addConstraints(constraints)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constraint between sibling views cannot be installed on either sibling, but must be installed on a common ancestor.

From the *Installing Constraints* section of Apple's [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH11-SW4):

> The view that holds the constraint must be an ancestor of the views
>   the constraint involves, and should usually be the closest common
>   ancestor. (This is in the existing NSView API sense of the word ancestor, 
>   where a view is an ancestor of itself.) The constraint is interpreted in the coordinate system 
>   of that view.

If you want to retain this constraint, you would need to hold on to a reference to it, and manually add it to the correct superview when your view's superview changed, ideally in your view controller's `updateViewConstraints()` method.

Comment: Thanks. I need to spend some more time studying the docs. Gets more complex when constraints go several layers deep, along with VFL vs. without.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have to add the constraints to the super view, i.e. the view that contains `constrainObject` and `toSibling`.

Comment: But what if you would like to retain the sibling constraints, and the superview didnt matter (a "component" you would like to use in other views)?